# Using the correct driver for my WiFi adapter?

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers

I'm trying to install the PCE-N53 Asus wireless adapter on my machine. After following the instructions [here](https://github.com/mareksuscak/asus-pce-n53-linux) and rebooting, I noticed that my machine is still using the "rt2860" driver:

```
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard [1458:e000]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169

06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT5592 PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1814:5592]
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:851a]
        Kernel driver in use: rt2860
```

Is this correct? I have been having some issues with slow/unstable WiFi since I started using the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than pointing to a link and saying "I did that", it would have helped if you had shown us the commands you executed, probably (but not certainly):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r)
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/mareksuscak/asus-pce-n53-linux.git
cd asus-pce-n53-linux
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rt5592sta
```

But with the results (what your system responded to these commands). Lacking the results (maybe something failed), I can only guess.

You can list loaded modules with `lsmod`, try:

```
lsmod | egrep 'rt5592sta|rt2860'
man lsmod
```

This step will take your WiFi offline while the commands execute, so BEWARE!

```
# force rt2860 to vacate
sudo rmmod rt2860

# reload rt5592sta
sudo modprobe rt5592sta

# see what happened
dmesg -T
```

If this does not help, post the results of the commands. Reading `man script` may help you do this.

If you cannot get WiFi to come up, you could:

```
# restore previous state
sudo modprobe rt2860
```

Comment: `rt2860` doesn't appear when I run `lsmod`, and `rmmod rt2860` returns  `rmmod: ERROR: Module rt2860 is not currently loaded
`. However, it still appears as the driver in use when I run `lspci -nnk`.

Comment: Do `lsmod | sort | less` and see if it is called something like `rt2860abc`